# Which of the three forbidden fruits was the opinion of the Arizal; grapes, wheat or figs and why?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, arizal

We were asked earlier this week about what the Arizal's opinion was on which forbidden fruit was on the Etz HaDaat. Does anyone know what it might be?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ariel. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Arizal? IIRC it's an explicit argument in the Talmud.

Comment: As @DannySchoemann commented, and evident from the title of this Q that you're likewise aware, there are three tannaitic opinions (Berachot [40a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.40a.14?with=all&lang=bi)); do you have reason to believe the Arizal opined one way or another?

Comment: @mbloch from the Zohar which you linked, we only see that Noach took the Grapes from Gan-Eden. How do you know they were from the  Eitz-Hadaas?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore see note 696 [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=gHXqB_ITcDoC&lpg=RA1-PA433&ots=Gmp929d-1g&dq=zohar%20fruit%20gan%20eden%20grape%20noah&pg=RA1-PA433#v=onepage&q=zohar%20fruit%20gan%20eden%20grape%20noah&f=false)

Comment: @mbloch ok. thank you, your original zohar link only highlighted the first paragraph about taking the grapes, not the following 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a view based on Midrash, gemara ([Brakhot 40a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.40a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and [Zohar](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.73a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the fruit of the Etz HaDaat was the grape and that Noah planted grapes ([Bereshit 9:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) upon leaving the Ark in an attempt to rectify the sin of the forbidden fruit.

Since the Ari was a major kabbalistic teacher, my guess is that he followed that explanation but I don't yet have a formal source in his writings

In more detail R Moshe Miller writes [here](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2388376/jewish/Drunk-on-Dvine.htm)

> One maintained that the grapevine was banished from the Garden of Eden
>   [i.e. it was the Tree of Knowledge, according to one of the views
>   cited (Bereishit Rabbah 15:8 and Sanhedrin 70b)] and [Noah] planted it
>   here [in the ground - outside of the Garden of Eden].
>
> According to the opinion that the vine was banished together with Adam
>   from the Garden of Eden, Noah intended to rectify the vine with which
>   Adam had transgressed. However, instead of sanctifying the wine which
>   he made from the grapes, he became drunk on it. He thus debased
>   himself by repeating Adam's sin, as explained below. The sin of the
>   Tree of Knowledge was that Adam drank the juice which Eve squeezed
>   from its grapes.
>
> **Rabbi Shimon [bar Yochai] said**: This verse contains the secret of wisdom. When Noah
>   wished to examine the sin that Adam had committed with the intention
>   of avoiding it himself and learning how to rectify it and the world,
>   he was unable to [fathom its secret]. So he squeezed grapes in order
>   to examine [the secret of] the vineyard.
>
> **The Zohar states that Eve squeezed grapes from the Tree of Knowledge
>   and gave Adam to drink.** (Zohar I, 36a, 267b) Ziv Hazohar explains that
>   this refers to "external" or secular wisdom, i.e. wisdom other than
>   the Torah, such as philosophy, which attempts to examine divine
>   secrets by way of the intellect; or witchcraft, which attempts to
>   harness the powers of impurity.